# Database query and hashed password for a database login

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I've been following the code provided by https://dzone.com/articles/ceate-a-login-system-using-html-php-and-mysql to create a login system for my database. I can register an account with no problems, but when I try to login using the credentials I just entered in the register page I get an invalid password message.  At first I thought it was a hashed password issue that I was messing up because of the invalid password error but now it almost seems like it's not processing the query correctly because when I add a `print_r($query)` I get mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => -1 ... printed out to the page.  Does anyone see where I'm going amiss?  Here is the code that I'm using for the login.

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
require_once "session.php";

$error = '';
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    if (empty($email)) {
        $error .= '<p class="error">Please enter your email.</p>';
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        $error .= '<p class="error">Please enter your password.</p>';
    }
    if (empty($error)) {
        if($query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?")) {
            $query->bind_param('s', $email);
            $query->execute();
            $row = $query->fetch();
            print_r($query);
            if ($row) {
                if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
                    $_SESSION["userid"] = $row['id'];
                    $_SESSION["user"] = $row;

                    header("location: welcome.php");
                    exit;
                } else {
                    echo("Password invalid<br><br>");
                    $error .= '<p class="error">The password is not valid.</p>';
                }
            } else {
                echo("Email invalid");
                $error .= '<p class="error">Email address is incorrect.</p>';
            }
        }
        $query->close();
    }
    mysqli_close($db);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2>Login</h2>
                    <p>Please enter your email and password.</p>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                        <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.php">Register here</a>.</p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the code for the register.php

```
<?php

require_once "config.php";
require_once "session.php";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST" && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fullname = trim($_POST['name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $confirm_password = trim($_POST['confirm_password']);
    $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    if($query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?")) {
        $error = '';
        $query->bind_param('s',$email);
        $query->execute();

        $query->store_result();
        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            $error .= '<p class="error">The email address is already registered!</p>';
        } else {
            if (strlen($password ) < 6) {
                $error .= '<p class="error">Password must have at least 6 characters.</p>';
            }
            if (empty($confirm_password)) {
                $error .= '<p class="error">Please enter confirm password.</p>';
            } else {
                if (empty($error) && ($password != $confirm_password)) {
                    $error .= '<p class="error">Passwords do not match.</p>';
                }
            }
            if (empty($error) ) {
                $insertQuery = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?);");
                $insertQuery->bind_param("sss", $fullname, $email, $password_hash);
                $result = $insertQuery->execute();
                if ($result) {
                    $error .= '<p class="success">Your registration was successful!</p>';
                } else {
                    $error .= '<p class="error">Something went wrong!</p>';
                }
                echo($password);
            }
        }
    }
    $query->close();
    $insertQuery->close();
    mysqli_close($db);
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Sign Up</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col=md=12">
                    <h2>Register</h2>
                    <p>Please complete this form to create an account.</p>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label> Full Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Confirm Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                        <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Login here</a>.</p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us the code you use to store that password, probably teh register script

Comment: It would be more useful to see what is $row by doing a `print_r($row)`

Comment: RiggsFolly, I updated the question to provide you with the code for the register as well.  I just added a """print_r($row)""" statement under """if($row){""" and it prints the number 1 to the top of the page.

Comment: If the database column big enough to store a hashed password, or could it be getting truncated when you store it?

Comment: droopsnoot, the 'id' is int(11), 'name' is varchar(75), 'password' is varchar(255), and 'email' is varchar(100) as per the tutorial provided in the link.

Comment: I don't use mysqli as I prefer PDO, but I think you have to use `bind_result()` if you're going to use `fetch()` to get results from a query. See the example here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: droopsnoot, your thought of needing to use bind_result got me down the right track.  If you want to post that as an answer I can give you the SO credit for answering the question.